# How to design an interface including multiprocessing in Python?

Tags: python, package, multiprocessing, python-3.10

I am pretty new in the context of Python programming and code design, so I wanted to ask a question about how to design code right in my example declared in title.

My code includes a client and a server. They are used to obtain and send information to a third-party-program which API is not supported via Python, so I have to communicate via rpc while the server is written in C#. The content of neither the server nor the client is important in this question. (If it is, I can share it later on)

So now I have it in a structure like:

```
src
├── main.py
├── client
│   ├── ...
└── server
    ├── ...
```

Right now the code of my main.py looks like:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from ctypes import c_int
from multiprocessing import Value

_SERVER_PROCESS:mp.Process
_RPC_SERVER:server.Server
_RUN_SERVER_FLAG:Value

def initServer() -> None:
    global _RUN_SERVER_FLAG
    _RUN_SERVER_FLAG = Value(c_int, 1)

    global _RPC_SERVER
    _RPC_SERVER = server.Server()

    global _SERVER_PROCESS
    _SERVER_PROCESS = mp.Process(target=_RPC_SERVER.serve, args=(_RUN_SERVER_FLAG,))
    _SERVER_PROCESS.start()

def closeServer() -> None:
    _RPC_SERVER.cancel(_RUN_SERVER_FLAG)
    _SERVER_PROCESS.join()

def connect(adr:str) -> None:
    client.connect(adr)

def disconnect() -> None:
    client.disconnect()

def testClientServerConnection(name:str) -> None:
    client.sayHello(name)
```

When I test the code with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    initServer()

    sleep(5)

    connect('127.0.0.1:5000')
    testClientServerConnection('Client')
    disconnect()

    closeServer()
```

It all works fine and as expected.

> _SERVER_PROCESS stores the process which starts the server

> _RPC_SERVER is my server class

> _RUN_SERVER_FLAG is a c_int used as Boolean. 0 does mean that the server stops and 1 keeps it running

Later, I want to provide my code as package for other python scripts, so that they can start and obtain information from the rpc-server.

Now I have my process, server and flag declared as global.
As I understood, using the global statement should be avoided when possible.

Is there a way for my code shown above to avoid using the global statement?

Is there anything I did wrong or could do better with the "design" of the code or the structure of my project?

Please feel free to correct me or ask any question regarding the topic!
Thanks for your answers and hopefully this can be of help to other than me too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is an object-oriented language that supports classes, which are ideal for encapsulation:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from ctypes import c_int
from multiprocessing import Value

class ClientServer:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # Where is client defined? It seems like it should be saved here:
        self.client = '?' # Initialize this with actual client
        # Where is server defined?
        self._RPC_SERVER = server.Server()
        self._RUN_SERVER_FLAG = Value(c_int, 1)
        self._SERVER_PROCESS = mp.Process(target=self._RPC_SERVER.serve, args=(self._RUN_SERVER_FLAG,))
        self._SERVER_PROCESS.start()
        # sleep done here on the asumption that we must wait some time
        # before we can proceed with a connect
        sleep(5)

    def closeServer(self) -> None:
        self._RPC_SERVER.cancel(self._RUN_SERVER_FLAG)
        self._SERVER_PROCESS.join()

    def connect(self, adr:str) -> None:
        self.client.connect(adr)

    def disconnect(self) -> None:
        self.client.disconnect()

    def testClientServerConnection(self, name:str) -> None:
        self.client.sayHello(name)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    client_server = ClientServer()

    client_server.connect('127.0.0.1:5000')
    client_server.testClientServerConnection('Client')
    client_server.disconnect()

    client_server.closeServer()
```